# Play website video in android browser doesn't support flash

Tags: php, android, video

I wonder I got a website with several videos, each video has two file format (flv and mov), when I view videos on mobile device/smartphone, I use user agent to detect if apple's device will located the video with mov format and so on, I then tried on android device to played video with firefox and dolphin browser apps, the video can played in firefox where dolphin doesn't ('Flash version 9.0 or greater is required, you have no flash plugin installed').

I knew this is because of adobe flash no more support for mobile device, how can I fix this issue? maybe there is alternate way to allow user open video from browser by using stock video apps? Please advise, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically have to support some very old browsers, I  suggest that you move to HTML5 video.  Convert all your videos to mp4 (H.264+AAC) and ogg formats and instead of your flash code, include something like this in your HTML:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    No HTML5 video support.
</video>
```

The reason you need two different formats is that different browsers understand one format and don't understand the other.  Have a look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) to see what browsers support what formats.  You can include other formats too, e.g. webm.  Also, there are additional attributes available (e.g. you can specify an image to show before the video starts or you can autostart on load, etc.)  Google for *html video tag* to find more information.